# What could be the reson for piped answers (Yes/No) to a script failing in dockerfile but working in interactive bash on the container

Tags: bash, docker

While trying to set up a docker container I stumbled across something I don't know how to solve, understand or google.

I have a Dockerfile where I run a script. One layer of the Dockerfile is:

```
RUN cd /app/spinnaker-1.23.0.27-amd64 && \
    printf 'y\nn\n' | sh install_spinnaker.sh
```

Basically I copied that line from [some GitHub repo](https://github.com/justinblaber/multi_pyspin/blob/master/Dockerfile#L37).

When I try to build this Dockerfile with `docker build --tag=app .` it will run the `install_spinnaker.sh` until the very end but then crash with:

```
[Y/n] $ The command '/bin/sh -c cd /app/spinnaker-1.23.0.27-amd64 &&     printf 'y\nn\n' | sh install_spinnaker.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

On the other hand, when remove this line from the Dockerfile, build it, and then open a bash on the container with `docker run -ti app bash` and inside the container then run the same command, i.e.

```bsh
cd /app/spinnaker-1.23.0.27-amd64 && printf 'y\nn\n' | sh install_spinnaker.sh
```

it will just work.

Now, there are actually three [Y/n] questions. So `printf 'y\nn\n' | sh install_spinnaker.sh` should not work, either in the dockerfile nor the interactive bash I guess?

So I tried with a few different ones. The following seemed most plausible to me:

```
RUN cd /app/spinnaker-1.23.0.27-amd64 && \
    printf 'y\nn\nn\n' | sh install_spinnaker.sh
```

which I expected to work because there are three questions. But it doesn't work and I don't know why. On building the Dockerfile it gives the following at the end:

```
Installation complete.
Would you like to register the installed software?
[Y/n] $ error: process ID out of range

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
The command '/bin/sh -c cd /app/spinnaker-1.23.0.27-amd64 &&     printf 'y\nn\nn\n' | sh install_spinnaker.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I don't see my mistake here. Please if you see anything obvious, let me know.

Comment: Does using `RUN sh -c 'cd ... && printf "y\n..." | sh ...'` work?

Comment: I tried it out, but it doesn't help. Actually I think RUN gets translated to `/bin/sh -c` anyways. Thus with your suggestion the error I get is the same as above with the `error: process ID out of range.` and it sais now that `The command '/bin/sh -c sh -c 'cd /app/spinnaker-1.23.0.27-amd64 && printf "y\nn\nn\n" | sh install_spinnaker.sh'' returned a non-zero code: 1` Again on the last question of the script.

Comment: I just found out, that the install script also gives the same error when running it in the bash. So ther's actually something going wrong with the install script when I run it in my container. I 'solved' my problem by removing the lines with `sed -i '50,101d' install_spinnaker.sh` and now it does what I want it to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error with the `error: process ID out of range` also came up when running it in the container with `docker rum -ti bash`.
I just somehow didn't see the error and the installation was successful regardles. So I didn't notice and thought that the problem is somewhere with Docker which is not the case.

I managed to get what I want by removing all lines of the `install_spinnaker.sh` script I don't need, including the one which caused the error. It also removes a question, so there are now only two questions left in the script. To do that I do:

```bsh
sed -i '50,101d' install_spinnaker.sh`
```

before running the script.

In the Dockerfile the layer now looks like:

```
RUN cd /app/spinnaker-1.23.0.27-amd64 && \
    sed -i '50,101d' install_spinnaker.sh && \
    printf 'y\nn\n' | sh install_spinnaker.sh
```